# Gre question : finding length of sides of a triangle given the longest side length and each side has an integer length

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-inequality

Need help in understanding the solution given for the problem in textbook. Below is the question
[image: Question]

**Below is the solution**
[image: Answer]

Option F=10 is not an answer as its given that all 3 angles are different and if shortest side is 10 then the triangle will become isosceles triangle. But in above answer its states all 3 sides will become same and become equilateral. But how did it derived the 3rd side ? Similarly i could not understand other correct answers explanation eg How did it derived 7 in 4-7-10 (Choice A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the shortest side is $10$ and the longest side is $10$. The remaining length must be at least as long as the shortest side and cannot exceed the longest side as well. Hence the remaining length is $10$.

As for $A,B,C,D$, we just have to check that the sum of the two shortest side exceeds the the longest side. Hence for $A$, the question is can we find an integer $4<y< 10$ such that $4+y > 10$, hence we can choose $y=7$. Similar for the other options.

Comment: if longest and shortest side is 10; the remaining length can be anywhere between $0<x<20$ Why will it be equal to 10

Comment: if $x=11$, $11$ would have been the longest side instead isn't it? If $x=9$, $9$ would have been the shortest side instead isnt' it?

Answer (score 1):

Let the side lengths be $a < b <c$. If $a=10$ and we know $c=10$, then for $b$ to be an **integer**, the only possible value could be $b=10$ which would contradict that all sides have unequal lengths.

For other answers: keep in mind the triangle inequality: sum of two sides has to be bigger than the third side.  So if $a=4$ and $c=10$, then with $b$ an integer to satisfy $a+b>c$, we need $4+b>10$, same as $b>6$.